# Getting int from database, if int = a spesific value, do something. if not do something else

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, local

Lately,i have been working on my login system. Its been going pretty well until i tried to give my account staff priviligies. So, i created a new column in my members table called "Rank" and i set it as int(11). I set my users Rank to 7. And now, when i login to memberspage i want my account and all others with Rank 7 to have special priviligies. And users who has under 7 or over, doesnt get any special priviligies. So, heres some code on what i have tried.

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); 





$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Rank from members where memberID=?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $memberID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();





$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($result['Rank'] == 7)
{
echo "You are a staff member.";
}


if($result['Rank'] < 7)
{
echo "You are not a staff member.";
}



//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 




//define page title
$title = 'Members Page';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php'); 
?>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">

                <h2>Member only page - Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h2>
                <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
                <hr>

        </div>
    </div>


</div>

<?php 
//include header template
require('layout/footer.php'); 

?>
```

I dont get any errors, but i get the message saying "You are not a staff member" instead of You are a staff member. Even tho im logged in with user having Rank 7.. What am i missing here?? What more do i need to include and change?

Comment: First, do a dump of what `$result` contains.

Comment: What do you mean? should i delete $result or what comes after it in the if statement?

Comment: just deleted $result from the if statement, still doesnt work man :(

Comment: Change `$result['Rank']` to `$result[0]['Rank']`

Comment: When people say 'dump $result' or something like it, they mean use `$print_r($result)` or `var_dump($result)` to check the value of the variable

Comment: @Juned Thanks, but still didnt work with : if($result[0]['Rank'] == 7)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting "You are a staff member." printed when executing your code.

My best bet is that your connection to the database isn't working or you have a mistake in your query, maybe a typo.

To verify that, you should `var_dump()` your `$result` to see what you're getting from the database, like this:

```
...
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
...
```

In my case that prints the following:

```
array(1) { ["Rank"]=> string(1) "7" }
```

so I am able to get `"Rank"` out of `$result`.

Make sure that you get something similar.

Edit answer below:
Since the `$result` you are getting is `false`, try getting some information why your query failed like this:

Try this:

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($values);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($result === false) {
        var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
        echo "<br>";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: bool(false) You are not a staff member. is what i got when i run var_dump($result); waht does it mean?

Comment: That means you are not getting any result form the database. I am editing my answer to help you troubleshoot this.

Comment: thanks so much man, so when i tried the dumb and got the bool(false) message my code looked like this $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Rank from members where memberID=?'); but when i took the memberID=? and set it to memberID=39 which is my accounts ID, it worked and said im staff. But then, any other accounts i logged into with a id over 39, also gets the staff message, even tho they are not rank 7. How can i find out what the logged in users memberID is, so only those who has rank 7 gets the message?  And when i ran the code you edited i got this message :

Comment: array(1) { ["Rank"]=> string(1) "7" } You are a staff member.string(71) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty"

Comment: But if i my account doesnt have rank 7, i get the you are not staff message. So at least something is working. But when i change mine to 7, everyone at least registrered after me gets the staff message to, even tho they are not staff... whats the problem here?

Comment: My best guess is that the variable `$memberID` is not assigned the correct value. If you think my answer helped you solved your problem, please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: ok, what do you mean with not  assigned as the correct value?